# Apache Shiro - custom jdbc Realm - reading roles/permissions

Tags: java, postgresql, jakarta-ee, shiro

I'm implementing Apache Shiro into my web application and have problems getting started.

I want to load roles and permission from a postgreSQL database and perfoms checks if a user has a role/permission.

My Role-Right-System consists of the following:

User -> has Roles (multiple possible)

Role -> has Rights (multiple possible)

Roles can be assigned to multiple Users  & Rights can be assigned to multiple roles

a User-Role Assignment is always related to two other conditions:

- A Organisational Unit (called OE in my case)
- A Faculty

So basically the User "Faculty-Admin" may have the following:

- Role OE-Admin with all Rights for OE: 3 and Faculty: staff

so he can lets say 'manage_Users' of Faculty 'staff' of OE '3'

I know how to implement roles in shiro.ini file but since I have my roles/rights(permissions) inside a database I need them to load from there.

In the quickstart example of Shiro there is the following example:

```
# The 'goodguy' role is allowed to 'drive' (action) the winnebago (type) with
# license plate 'eagle5' (instance specific id)
goodguy = winnebago:drive:eagle5
```

If I take this example and apply it to my situation i get the following:

```
# The 'OE-Admin' role is allowed to 'manage_users' of OE '3' (type) with
# faculty 'staff'
OE-Admin = 3:manage_users:staff
```

so I have my role definition like this:

Role = OE:Right:Faculty (or change them in order, doenst matter really)

Now the big question is: How can I "load" my roles/rights from my database to get even this stated format of a role with its permissions??

So far I have the following inside shiro.ini:

```
ds = org.postgresql.Driver
ds.serverName = localhost
ds.user = admin
ds.password = admin
ds.databaseName = db_name
jdbcRealm = org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm
jdbcRealm.dataSource = $ds
jdbcRealm.permissionsLookupEnabled = true
```

I know there has to be an entry like "jdbcRealm.userRolesQuery = SELECT ...."
but I dont know how load roles the way I stated above.

Is it just an entry to the .ini file that will be equivalent to a static role set like this: goodguy = winnebago:drive:eagle5

or what steps are nessecary to accomplish that?

Any1 got more experiance with Apache Shiro that could possibly help me out?
There are some tutorials out there but I find it very hard to follow them for creating a custom jdbc realm with owm roles & permissions.

**EDIT:**
Database Structure:

Users:

```
id serial NOT NULL,
"user" character varying(50) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT umgmt_users_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

Roles:

```
id serial NOT NULL,
role character varying(50) NOT NULL,
priv_level integer NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT umgmt_roles_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

Rights(Permissions):

```
id serial NOT NULL,
"right" character varying(50) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT umgmt_rights_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

and just in case, this is my table where I store User-Role-OE-Fac Relations

```
id serial NOT NULL,
user_id integer NOT NULL,
oe_id integer NOT NULL,
fac_id integer NOT NULL,
role_id integer NOT NULL,
assigned_by_priv_level integer NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT umgmt_user_oe_fac_role_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
CONSTRAINT fac_fkey FOREIGN KEY (fac_id)
  REFERENCES umgmt_facultys (id) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT oe_fkey FOREIGN KEY (oe_id)
  REFERENCES umgmt_oes (id) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT role_fkey FOREIGN KEY (role_id)
  REFERENCES umgmt_roles (id) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT user_fkey FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
  REFERENCES umgmt_users (id) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
```

Comment: Very good question. Actually, I was troubled by something similar a few weeks back. Let me first of all try and understand your solution:

`Users are assigned Roles`, I am assuming each User has only **One** Role, but the same Role can be applied to **multiple** Users. A `Role is assigned Rights(Permissions?)`, again assuming each Role can have **Multiple** Permissions and likewise, the same Permission may be applied to more than One User.

Comment: **EDIT:** Please confirm if my above assumptions are correct.

Comment: users can have multiple roles, roles can have multiple permissions, each role/permission can be assigned to multiple users/roles. I edited my question above

Comment: Ok, next. Please include your database structure of your `User`, `Role` and `Permission` table to your original OP. The queries are dependant to your schema.

Comment: will put t hem in question since formatting comments is a mess here^^

Comment: Are you setting and storing all the entity relationships in a separate table?: The table for `User-Role-OE-Fac Relations`, this is more complex and there are simpler ways. Additionally, what is `priv_level` in the Role table for? I see no reference of this in your structure.

Comment: yeah I have a table where I store the relation between users, roles, oe & faculty. priv_level is a value to determine which role has created a new relation to let only higher privileged roles alter/delete those

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97210/discussion-between-revxaisks-and-alkahna).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok after a long discussion with [RevXaisks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1792848/revxaisks) I will sleep one more night over this but I think Shiro does not fit my needs in terms of Role/Permisson checks.
Thanks a lot buddy as you were so patient.